# why AsyncHttpClient method calls both onSuccess and onFailure method simultaneously

Tags: android, json, rest, android-async-http

I don't understand why both the methods are called simultaneously ie onSuccess and onFailure method of AsyncHttpClient. Here is the following code snippet.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject obj)
        {
            System.out.print("Inside success method....");
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Inside try of success method");

                if ("SUCCESS".equals(obj.getString("status")))
                {
                    System.out.println("Status   :  " + obj.getString("status"));
                    statusFlag = statusFlag+1;
                    System.out.println("Double Status Flag: "+statusFlag);
                }
                else
                {
                    //statusFlag = 2;
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                //statusFlag = 3;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse)
        {
            if (statusCode == 404)
            {
                //statusFlag = 4;
            }
            else if (statusCode == 500)
            {
                //statusFlag = 5;
            }
            else
            {
                //statusFlag = 6;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: why the statusFlag value is not changing in onSuccess method

Comment: What do you mean is not changing are you asigning to it any value?

Comment: Yes I am assigning the value when it calls the success method